# Adding grouped geom_vline to multiple facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, grouping

I am trying to add vertical lines that should be specific to each plot facet. I am attempting to do this by grouping the geom_vline data by the same process as the plot data are grouped. The vertical data are from a different dataframe than the points are. The lines of code below are what I have.

```
plots <-
  dd %>%
   ggplot(aes(Date, TDS)) +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_point(aes(group = Well, color = Well), size = 1) +
    ggtitle(paste("WMA A-AX TDS")) +
    ylab("mg/L") +
    geom_smooth(aes(group= Well), method = "loess", color = "black",  se = FALSE) +
    geom_vline(data = cpdates, aes(group = Well_LOC, xintercept=as.numeric(CPT_DATE)), color ="blue", lwd=0.5, lty=1) +
    facet_grid(Well~.)
```

This code however does not group the geom_vline data but puts all of the lines in all of the facets. The grouping works for the points and the LOESS lines so why not the vlines?

[image: Example plot with excess vertical lines in facets]

I have tried numerous things to solve this but nothing works. Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to have the exact same values in `cpdates$Well` as `dd$Well` does if you want `ggplot()` to facet for you.

Comment: Those values are the same but the number of rows differ between the two. I will try to shore those up and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facets don't use the group aesthetic. The plot is faceting on `Well`, so `cpdates` needs a `Well` variable.

Here is some dummy data to reproduce the problematic plot.

```
library('ggplot2')
library('dplyr')

cpdates <- data.frame(
  Well_LOC = c(4, 5, 6, 8),
  CPT_DATE = c(1, 2, 3,4))

dd <- data.frame(
  Date = mpg$displ,
  TDS = mpg$cty,
  Well = mpg$cyl)


dd %>%
 ggplot(aes(Date, TDS)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point(aes(group = Well, color = Well), size = 1) +
  ggtitle(paste("WMA A-AX TDS")) +
  ylab("mg/L") +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = Well), method = "loess", color = "black",  se = FALSE) +
  geom_vline(data = cpdates, aes(group = Well_LOC, xintercept=as.numeric(CPT_DATE)), color ="blue", lwd=0.5, lty=1) +
  facet_grid(Well~.)
```

[image: bad plot]

Adding `Well` to `cpdates` fixes the problem. We can also get rid of the `group` asthetic.

```
cpdates$Well = cpdates$Well_LOC

dd %>%
 ggplot(aes(Date, TDS)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point(aes(group = Well, color = Well), size = 1) +
  ggtitle(paste("WMA A-AX TDS")) +
  ylab("mg/L") +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", color = "black",  se = FALSE) +
  geom_vline(data = cpdates, aes(xintercept=as.numeric(CPT_DATE)), color ="blue", lwd=0.5, lty=1) +
  facet_grid(Well~.)
```

[image: fixed plot]